# Unresolved variable Schema when using WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, webstorm

I am using WebStorm and I have enabled Node Modules in which I have JavaScript Standard Style ( https://standardjs.com ) and it works fine. It underlines when I have ';' or anything like this (basically not following the standard ). When I use mongoose ( `const mongoose = require('mongoose')` you most probably are familiar with it) and I decide to create model and make the following code

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required: true},
  profilePicture: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required: false},
})
```

There are more fields but the code is repeating. WebStorm gives me hints about what is in `mongoose`, `Schema` and `Types`, but it underlines them and gives the following

> Unresolved variable Schema

and after that

> Unresolved variable Types

Here is how it looks 
[image]

It should not give me any errors while compiling but it is quite annoying when trying to follow the standard because I get lots of errors about stuff like "expected 6 spaces found 8" and I check every error and see stuff like this. Does anyone know how to fix it?

EDIT: Managed to fix "Unresolved Variable Schema" by disabling Node Modules coding assistance ( Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM) ,but now things like `required` are Unresolved. Here is a picture
[image]

Is there a way to have my Node.js hints and also WebStorm understanding `mongoose` and other objects and their properties?

Btw - This `TODO` you are seeing - is because WebStorm gives me hints about ObjectID being with capital D, while in other places it is with lower D. This shit crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is relevant for anyone at this point but to solve these mongoose related unresolved variable squigglies in WebStorm you need to go to

***File > Settings...***

[image]

Under ***Languages & Frameworks***, you'll need to select the ***JavaScript*** (not *Node.js and NPM*) category.

Under that category select ***Libraries***.

[image]

If you have not downloaded any additional libraries to be used, you'll probably see a list similar to something like this:

[image]

On the right of the list select the ***Download...*** button.

[image]

A window with a list of libraries will pop up, scroll down until you find mongoose, select it and hit the Download and Install button.

[image]

After that, your list of libraries will probably look something like this:

[image]

Webstorm should now be able to understand mongoose related types and variables etc, and should also provide auto-complete options for those as well.