# How can I get WebStorm to recognize the NodeJS module object?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

[image: module object underlined because Webstorm can resolve the dependancy]

When I am creating a NodeJS module to be exported, the module object is not recognized.  Is there a way to get this module object ot be recognized.  I looked under the Settings&Framworks > Node and that appears to be correct.  Although I can't seem to keep the "Coding assistance for Node.js"  checked (it keeps clearing the 'check')

I looked through IntelliJ's Reference Material [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-node-js-applications.html)

I actually may be coding incorrectly as well, perhaps I'm not supposed to hook into this 'exports' object in this manor.
Advice and guidance appreciated.

Comment: What IDE and Node.js versions do you use? The right way to get Node.js core functions resolved is enabling **Coding assistance for Node.js** per instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-node-js-applications.html#nodeInterpreter; if it doesn't work for you, please share your idea.log (**Help > show Log in ...**)

Answer (score 0):

First this question is very similar to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978805/unresolved-variable-schema-when-using-webstorm)

First I went to the settings (Ctrl-Alt-S) and 
'Language & Frameworks' > JavaScript > Libraries

Then I hit the Download button till I found a bunch of node libraries. I figured this was a very 'basic' node object so I used the plain 'node' libary.

[image]

Then the @types/node was present for me to enable

[image]